# More efficient method in order to replicate function VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Evening all,

I'm having a little trouble with some code I've been working on and was wondering if anybody would be able to help me.

I have an Excel worksheet where I need to automatically add box sizes using a Vlookup then lock cells unless 'Other' has been selected and replace the formulas if they've been deleted. Everything is working perfectly writing the code for each line separately. However I need to run this for 700+ rows and I'm not writing this out 700 times because that would be ridiculous. I've tried various loops to solve this but I'm stuck.

Can somebody show me how to efficiently run this for x amount of rows?
So this works perfectly for row 11 and when written x amount of times it works for multiple rows. I'm probably going to kick myself when the solution is shown, this is so frustrating.

```
Private Sub lock_repair(ByVal Target As Range)
'Box 1
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="pass"
If Target.Cells(1).Address = "$C$11" And Target.Cells(1).Value <> "OTHER" Then
    Range("D11").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C11, Data!$D$5:$G$24, 2,FALSE),0)"
    Range("E11").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C11, Data!$D$5:$G$24, 3,FALSE),0)"
    Range("F11").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C11, Data!$D$5:$G$24, 4,FALSE),0)"

    ActiveSheet.Range("D11:F11").Locked = True

ElseIf Target.Cells(1).Address = "$C$11" And Target.Cells(1).Value = "OTHER" Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("D11:F11").Locked = False


End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Cheers in advance.
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. You need to test this on a backup first.

```
    Private Sub lock_repair(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Box 1
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="pass"
    If Target.Cells(1).Column = 3 And Target.Cells(1).Value <> "OTHER" Then
        Range("D" & Target.Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & Target.Row & ", Data!$D$5:$G$24, 2,FALSE),0)"
        Range("E" & Target.Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & Target.Row & ", Data!$D$5:$G$24, 3,FALSE),0)"
        Range("F" & Target.Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & Target.Row & ", Data!$D$5:$G$24, 4,FALSE),0)"

        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).Locked = True

    ElseIf Target.Cells(1).Column = 3 And Target.Cells(1).Value = "OTHER" Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).Locked = False


    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    End Sub
```